# Get ClusterName of MQ Queue using Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm building a java application that connects to a MQQueueManager and extracts information about queues. I'm able to get data like `QueueType`, `MaximumMessageLength` and more. However, I also want the name of the cluster the queue might be in. There is no function that comes with the MQQueue that gives me this information. After searching the internet I found several things pointing in this direction, but no examples.

A part of my function that gives me the `MaximumDepth` is:

```
    queueManager = makeConnection(host, portNo, qMgr, channelName);
    queue = queueManager.accessQueue(queueName, CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);
    maxQueueDepth = queue.getMaximumDepth();
```

(`makeConnection` is not shown here, it is the function that makes the actual connection to the QueueManager; I also left out the try/catch/finally for less clutter)

How do I get `ClusterName` and perhaps other data, that doesn't have a function like `queue.getMaximumDepth()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I finally found what I was looking for.
This example of IBM: [Getting and setting attribute values in WebSphere MQ classes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031010_.htm]) helped me to set up the inquiry.

The necessary values I found in this list: [Constant Field Values](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/nl/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/constant-values.html).

I also needed to expand the `openOptionsArg` of `accessQueue()`, else cluster queues cannot be inquired.

Final result:
(without `makeConnection()`)

```
public class QueueManagerServices {

final static int MQOO_INQUIRE_TOTAL = CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;

MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
String cluster = null;
MQQueue queue = null;

public String getcluster(String host, int portNo, String qMgr, String channelName){

 try{
  queueManager = makeConnection(host, portNo, qMgr, channelName);
  queue = queueManager.accessQueue(queueName, MQOO_INQUIRE_TOTAL);

  int MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME = 2029;
  int MQ_CLUSTER_NAME_LENGTH = 48;

  int[] selectors = new int[1];
  int[] intAttrs = new int[1];
  byte[] charAttrs = new byte[MQ_CLUSTER_NAME_LENGTH];

  selectors[0] = MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME;

  queue.inquire(selectors, intAttrs, charAttrs);

  cluster = new String (charAttrs);

  } catch (MQException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  } finally {
      if (queue != null){
        queue.close();
      }
      if (queueManager != null){
        queueManager.disconnect();
      }
  }
  return cluster;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't hard-coded values but use the MQ defined ones.  i.e. CMQC.MQ_CLUSTER_NAME_LENGTH and CMQC.MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME

Comment: Also, you should wrap the queue.close() in a try/catch because if it throws an exception then the disconnect will never be called.  And of course, the disconnect should be wrapped in a try/catch to control any failures for the disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get information about a queue.

The API Inquire call gets operational status of a queue. This includes things like the name the `MQOpen` call resolved to or the depth if the queue is local. Much of the `q.inquire` functionality has been superseded with getter and setter functions on the queue.  If you are not using the [v8.0 client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24037500&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) with the latest functionality, you are highly advised to upgrade.  It can access all versions of QMgr.

The following code is from *[Getting and setting attribute values in WebSphere MQ classes for Java](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/ja11150_.htm)*

```
// inquire on a queue
final static int MQIA_DEF_PRIORITY = 6;
final static int MQCA_Q_DESC = 2013;
final static int MQ_Q_DESC_LENGTH = 64;

int[] selectors  = new int[2];
int[] intAttrs   = new int[1];
byte[] charAttrs = new byte[MQ_Q_DESC_LENGTH]

selectors[0] = MQIA_DEF_PRIORITY;
selectors[1] = MQCA_Q_DESC;

queue.inquire(selectors,intAttrs,charAttrs);

System.out.println("Default Priority = " + intAttrs[0]);
System.out.println("Description : " + new String(charAttrs,0));
```

For things that are not part of the API Inquire call, a PCF command is needed.  Programmable Command Format, commonly abbreviated as PCF, is a message format used to pass messages to the command queue and for reading messages from the command queue, event queues and others.

To use a PCF command the calling application must be authorized with `+put` on `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE` and for `+dsp` on the object being inquired upon.

IBM provides sample code.
On Windows, please see: `%MQ_FILE_PATH%\Tools\pcf\samples`
In UNIX flavors, please see: `/opt/mqm/samp/pcf/samples`
The locations may vary depending on where MQ was installed.

Please see: [Handling PCF messages with IBM MQ classes for Java](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030980_.htm?lang=en). The following snippet is from the `PCF_DisplayActiveLocalQueues.java` sample program.

```
  public static void DisplayActiveLocalQueues(PCF_CommonMethods pcfCM) throws PCFException,
      MQDataException, IOException {
    // Create the PCF message type for the inquire.
    PCFMessage pcfCmd = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);

    // Add the inquire rules.
    // Queue name = wildcard.
    pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");

    // Queue type = LOCAL.
    pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQConstants.MQQT_LOCAL);

    // Queue depth filter = "WHERE depth > 0".
    pcfCmd.addFilterParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH, MQConstants.MQCFOP_GREATER, 0);

    // Execute the command. The returned object is an array of PCF messages.
    PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = pcfCM.agent.send(pcfCmd);

    // For each returned message, extract the message from the array and display the
    // required information.
    System.out.println("+-----+------------------------------------------------+-----+");
    System.out.println("|Index|                    Queue Name                  |Depth|");
    System.out.println("+-----+------------------------------------------------+-----+");

    for (int index = 0; index < pcfResponse.length; index++) {
      PCFMessage response = pcfResponse[index];

      System.out.println("|"
          + (index + pcfCM.padding).substring(0, 5)
          + "|"
          + (response.getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME) + pcfCM.padding).substring(0, 48)
          + "|"
          + (response.getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH) + pcfCM.padding)
              .substring(0, 5) + "|");
    }

    System.out.println("+-----+------------------------------------------------+-----+");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had found information apout the inquire call, but I couldnt get it to work. Do you have an example for that too?

Comment: Check out `%MQ_FILE_PATH%\Tools\soap\samples\java\clients\RunIvt.java`

Comment: I can't find something I can use in the example; the only part where a queue is inquired is in the last class and it uses a standard function (`q.getOpenInputCount()`), but perhaps I'm not looking correctly.

Comment: For your Inquire, please don't hard-coded values but use the MQ defined ones.  i.e. CMQC.MQIA_DEF_PRIORITY, CMQC.MQCA_Q_DESC and CMQC.MQ_Q_DESC_LENGTH